# Creating a dynamic network within R

Tags: r, network-programming

Im aiming to create a network dynamic however every time I convert my network to a network dynamic the heads and tails change from those inputted from excel and I am unsure why?

Here is the code I used:

```
nodes <- read.csv("NODES_2.csv", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE) #Assigns nodes in excel to variable nodes. Header = TRUE ensures that the top row is counted as a header.
edges <- read.csv("EDGES_2.csv", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE) #Assigns edges in excel to variable edges. Header = FALSE ensures that the top row is not counted as a header.


thenetwork <- network(
  edges,
  vertex.attr = nodes,
  vertex.attrnames = c("vertex.id", "Name", "Node Type", "Type Label", "Int Type", "Int Type Label", "Institution Name"),
  directed = FALSE,
  bipartite = FALSE,
  multiple = TRUE)

plot(thenetwork)


dynamicnodes <- read.csv("NODES_2_DYNAMIC.csv", header=TRUE)
dynamicedges <- read.csv("EDGES_2_DYNAMIC.csv", header=TRUE)

thedynamicnetwork <- networkDynamic(base.net=thenetwork, edge.spells = dynamicedges, vertex.spells=dynamicnodes)

plot(thedynamicnetwork)
as.data.frame(thedynamicnetwork)
```

Followed multiple tutorials which don't seem to have the same problem

Comment: Please use `dput` for `nodes` and `edges` to make this more of a reproducible example. Also, include which packages you are using (e.g., I don't know what package contains `network()`). See this article for more on creating a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example